# I installed my custom python package but it could not work

Tags: python

I created my custom package and installed it by `pip install -e .`, but after I `import mypackage`, I cannot use any submodules of the package.

My file structure:

```
jjnutils
├─ jjnutils
    ├─ __init__.py
    ├─ myutil.py
    ├─ patch.py
├─ LICENSE
├─ README.md
├─ setup.py
```

`__init__.py` is empty.
In my `setup.py`:

```
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name="jjnutils", # Replace with your own username
    version="0.0.1",
    author="Jingnan",
    author_email="jiajingnan2222@gmail.com",
    description="A packages containing common utils functions",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="https://github.com/Ordgod/jjnutils",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.6',
)
```

### How do I install my custom package?

`cd /home/jjnutils`

`pip install -e .`

### How do I use it?

In python internative ternamil:
`import jjnutils`
It was successful.

`jjnutils.patch.function()`
It showed Error: AttributeError: module 'jjnutils' has no attribute 'patch'

`dir(jjnutils)`
It showed:  `['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']`

Could anyone tell me why???

Comment: Nothing wrong with your packaging.  Use `import jjnutils.patch`.